# How do I compute the linear index of a 3D coordinate and vice versa?

Tags: arrays, math, multidimensional-array, matrix, coordinate-transformation

If I have a point (x, y z), how do I find the linear index, i for that point? My numbering scheme would be (0,0,0) is 0, (1, 0, 0) is 1, . . ., (0, 1, 0) is the max-x-dimension, ....
Also, if I have a linear coordinate, i, how do I find (x, y, z)?
I can't seem to find this on google, all the results are filled with other irrelevant stuff. Thank you!

Comment: Are the coordinates always composed of integers? can you have negative coordinates? Do you have maximums for any axes besides the x axis?

Comment: Does each coordinate have the same number of divisions, or different? The last point is represented by `(N,N,N)` or `(N1,N2,N3)`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a few ways to map a 3d coordinate to a single number. Here's one way.

some function f(x,y,z) gives the linear index of coordinate(x,y,z). It has some constants a,b,c,d which we want to derive so we can write a useful conversion function.

```
f(x,y,z) = a*x + b*y + c*z + d
```

You've specified that (0,0,0) maps to 0. So:

```
f(0,0,0) = a*0 + b*0 + c*0 + d = 0
d = 0
f(x,y,z) = a*x + b*y + c*z
```

That's d solved.
You've specified that (1,0,0) maps to 1. So:

```
f(1,0,0) = a*1 + b*0 + c*0 = 1
a = 1
f(x,y,z) = x + b*y + c*z
```

That's a solved.
Let's arbitrarily decide that the next highest number after (MAX_X, 0, 0) is (0,1,0).

```
f(MAX_X, 0, 0) = MAX_X
f(0, 1, 0) = 0 + b*1 + c*0 = MAX_X + 1
b = MAX_X + 1
f(x,y,z) = x + (MAX_X + 1)*y + c*z
```

That's b solved.
Let's arbitrarily decide that the next highest number after (MAX_X, MAX_Y, 0) is (0,0,1).

```
f(MAX_X, MAX_Y, 0) = MAX_X + MAX_Y * (MAX_X + 1)
f(0,0,1) = 0 + (MAX_X + 1) * 0  + c*1 = MAX_X + MAX_Y * (MAX_X + 1) + 1
c = MAX_X + MAX_Y * (MAX_X + 1) + 1
c = (MAX_X + 1) + MAX_Y * (MAX_X + 1)
c = (MAX_X + 1) * (MAX_Y + 1)
```

now that we know a, b, c, and d, we can write your function as follows:

```
function linearIndexFromCoordinate(x,y,z, max_x, max_y){
    a = 1
    b = max_x + 1
    c = (max_x + 1) * (max_y + 1)
    d = 0
    return a*x + b*y + c*z + d
}
```

You can get the coordinate from the linear index by similar logic. I have a truly marvelous demonstration of this, which this page is too small to contain. So I'll skip the math lecture and just give you the final method.

```
function coordinateFromLinearIndex(idx, max_x, max_y){
    x =  idx % (max_x+1)
    idx /= (max_x+1)
    y = idx % (max_y+1)
    idx /= (max_y+1)
    z = idx
    return (x,y,z)
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I guess I'll just puzzle over your marvelous proof for 375 more years (but it makes sense now). Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Kevin
Hello! I realize that this question is almost 2 years old, but I was wondering: Would you maybe have a link to that math lecture you mentioned? Your method seems absolutely fantastic, so I was curious about the math behind it all.

Comment: you shouldn't alter code in edits after the answer is accepted - it shuold be done in a comment.

Comment: @MarkAnderson, if I recall correctly, the math lecture only existed in my head while I was composing `coordinateFromLinearIndex`. I could edit the answer to show how I derived the final code block, but first I need to remember how I did it :-)

Comment: Can I interest you in the virtues of the [`divmod()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod)? I'm sure `coordinateFromLinearIndex()` could benefit from its unique properties.

Comment: Bookmarked! Great explanation of the math behind the algorithm.

Comment: @Kevin is there any generic algorithm to make this conversion for higher dimensional arrays ? Let's say arrays with dimension 4 and 5 ?

Comment: For anyone who lands on this page seeking a "truly marvelous" demonstration, see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3758576/how-to-convert-from-a-flattened-3d-index-to-a-set-of-coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no upper limit on the coordinates, you can number them from origo and outwards. Layer by layer.

```
(0,0,0) -> 0
(0,0,1) -> 1
(0,1,0) -> 2
(1,0,0) -> 3
(0,0,2) -> 4
   :       :
(a,b,c) -> (a+b+c)·(a+b+c+1)·(a+b+c+2)/6 + (a+b)·(a+b+1)/2 + a
```

The inverse is harder, since you would have to solve a 3rd degree polynomial.

```
m1 = InverseTetrahedralNumber(n)
m2 = InverseTriangularNumber(n - Tetra(m1))
a = n - Tetra(m1) - Tri(m2)
b = m2 - a
c = m1 - m2
```

where

```
InverseTetrahedralNumber(n) = { x ∈ ℕ | Tetra(n) ≤ x < Tetra(n+1) } 
Tetra(n) = n·(n+1)·(n+2)/6 
InverseTriangularNumber(n) = { x ∈ ℕ | Tri(n) ≤ x < Tri(n+1) } 
Tri(n) = n·(n+1)/2
```

`InverseTetrahedralNumber(n)` could either be calculated from the [large analytic solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Roots_of_a_cubic_function), or searched for with [some numeric method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).

---

Here is my attempt at an algebraic solution (javascript). I am using the substitutions `p = a+b+c`, `q = a+b`, `r = a` to simplify the equations.

```js
function index(a,b,c) {
    var r = a;
    var q = r + b;
    var p = q + c;
    return (p*(p+1)*(p+2) + 3*q*(q+1) + 6*r)/6;
}

function solve(n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return [0,0,0];
    }

    var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
    var cbrt = function (x) { return Math.pow(x,1.0/3); };

    var X = sqrt(729*n*n - 3);
    var Y = cbrt(81*n + 3*X);
    var p = Math.floor((Y*(Y-3)+3)/(Y*3));
    if ((p+1)*(p+2)*(p+3) <= n*6) p++;
    var pp = p*(p+1)*(p+2);

    var Z = sqrt(72*n+9-12*pp);
    var q = Math.floor((Z-3)/6);
    if (pp + (q+1)*(q+2)*3 <= n*6) q++;
    var qq = q*(q+1);

    var r = Math.floor((6*n-pp-3*qq)/6);
    if (pp + qq*3 + r*6 < n*6) r++;

    return [r, q - r, p - q];
}
```